# Xceed Docx Wrong paragraph spacing in table cells

Tags: c#, .net, docx, xceed

I am using the Xceed Docx library to generate a Word document which contains a lot of tables with the following formatting

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zerke.png)

The problem is that the library seems to insert a spacing before the cells' first paragraph, which renders as follows

[Actual rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zsAX.png)

Here's the code I use to generate the table

```
private Table InitTable(DocX document)
{
int rows = Util.ListNullOrEmpty(reponses) ? 3 : 2 + reponses.Count;
int columns = 6;

var table = document.AddTable(rows, columns);

table.Rows[0].MergeCells(4, 5);
table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Width = 34; // 12 mm
table.Rows[0].Cells[1].Width = 127.55; // 45 mm
table.Rows[0].Cells[2].Width = 104.88; // 37 mm
table.Rows[0].Cells[3].Width = 104.88; // 37 mm
table.Rows[0].Cells[4].Width = 104.88; // 37 mm

Border border = new Border(BorderStyle.Tcbs_thick, BorderSize.one, 10, System.Drawing.Color.Black);

List<string> enteteLigne1 = new List<string>
{
    "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5"
};

// Header : First row
for (int i = 0; i < columns -1; i++)
{
    SetCellBorder(table.Rows[0].Cells[i], border, 0b0000);
    FormatCellContent(table.Rows[0].Cells[i], enteteLigne1[i], "Arial", 10d, Alignment.center);
}

return table;
}

private void FormatCellContent(Cell cell, string content, string fontName, double fontSize, Alignment alignment)
{
var p = cell.Paragraphs.FirstOrDefault();
if (p == null)
{
    p = cell.InsertParagraph();
}

p.SpacingBefore(2.9); // 1 mm * 2.834645669 * 20 (OpenXML unit)
p.SpacingAfter(2.9);
p.Alignment = alignment;
p.Font(fontName);
p.FontSize(fontSize);
p.InsertText(content);

}
```

The only alternative is to insert OpenXml code into the paragraph's Xml property, but that would be tedious and somehow defies the purpose of using the library.

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

table.Rows[0].Cells[0].Width = 34;

use

table.SetColumnWidth(0, 34);

which will define the column width of the table

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

To solve this task, you can utilize a template string from the table. For instance:

```
var table = _document.Tables.LastOrDefault();
var templateRow = table.Rows[1]; // an empty row

foreach (var item in list)
{
    var row = table.InsertRow(templateRow);

    row.Cells[0].Paragraphs[0].Append(item.Title);
    // ...
}

table.RemoveRow(1);
```